# How to extend API dependend theme entries in an existing theme?

Tags: android, android-theme

In Android development I'm allowed to provide [API depending resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources). I've a custom theme which I would like to extend with two new entries for API 29 and higher as [described here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/gesturenav).

So the file/folder structure looks like that:

```
res
 - values
   - dark_theme.xml
   - light_theme.xml
 - values-v29
   - dark_theme.xml
   - light_theme.xml
```

How can I just extend (add items to the existing theme) the theme defined in `values\dark_theme.xml` and `values\light_theme.xml` in `values-v29\dark_theme.xml` and `values\light_theme.xml`?

Let's say I want to extend the light theme with the new options for ["edge-to-edge" feature](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/gesturenav#transparent-bars). How do I need to set up the theme so I don't need to copy all the values from the original theme to the theme in `-v29` folder?

Content of `values\light_theme.xml`:

```
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme_Light" parent="BaseAppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_light</item>
    ...
  </style>
</resources>
```

How does the file need to look like to use the items already defined in the theme in `values` folder without coping the whole theme?

Content of `values-29\light_theme.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme_Light" parent="BaseAppTheme">
  
  ...How to ensure all the previous items defined in values\light_theme.xml are used here?
  
  <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apparently](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#configuring-lint-checking-in-xml) it seems the way to go is to use the XML attribute

```
tools:ignore="NewApi"
```

from the [tools namespace](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#configuring-lint-checking-in-xml).

So I used those lines in my case instead of copying my styles files:

```
<style name="AppTheme_Light" parent="BaseAppTheme">
  
  ...
  
  <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:ignore="NewApi">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:ignore="NewApi">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

If this is good practice seems "[to depend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55803882)" because I hide possible incompatible widget attributes.